# Using Git, if during a newfeature branch, when we need to do a hot fix, should we create a hotfix branch?

Tags: git, git-branch

It seems that, let's say we have everything commit as "Version 1.0 done", and now we want to add a feature, it is good to create a branch, say `newfeature`, so that when we need a "hot fix" or "quick fix", we can switch between the `master` branch and the `newfeature` branch.

But I do see in an example that, the operation is:

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b hotfix

// now do any fix that is needed in Emacs

git commit -am "finished hot fix"
git checkout master
git merge hotfix
git branch -d hotfix       // delete the hotfix branch
```

The question is, should `hotfix` be created and go through all the merge and deletion of `hotfix`?  Why not just switch to the `master` branch and do the fix and commit it, and that's it?  Is there a good reason to create the `hotfix` branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using the master branch as develop branch its in my opinion usless to make another branch for hotfixes. But if you are using a branching model like [this](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/), its very usefull.

They are using seperate develop and master branches. The master branch is only for tagging release versions. So if your customer has a problem and you want to do a hotfix, you can make a hotfix branch from the master release tag. So the hotfix is comletely detached from your normal development branch and the customer only gets what he wants, the hotfix.

Merging and deleting branches is also ok. If you are using --no-ff you can reconstruct, that there was a merge.

Answer (score 1):

it's totally up to you.

I think a good strategy is to choose depending on the size of the fix. If a good developer is expected to change one or two files, a couple lines in each, you can do it on the master branch.

But, on the other hand, if there are 100 developers working on the project and a new developer has to provide a fix that is likely to imply a lot of work, 10+ files and 100+ lines to be changed, it is probably better and more comfortable to create the hotfix branch (and deleting it is good practice, as it becomes useless and even bothering).

The criteria to decide whether you need a specific branch is somewhere between these cases, and is your (or your admin's) decision.

Another case it is useful is if you work on different fixes/features at the same time and they are conflicting (e.g. configuration is different, or one does not compile any more, ...).

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are looking for some sort of a git work flow, I recomend the [git branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) by [Vincent Driessen](http://nvie.com/about/) known as [@nvie](https://github.com/nvie/) as well as the tool [git-flow](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow) written by him too. This really is an elegant way of working with git, you really need try it.